# How to typeset an independent and identical normal distribution (iidN) in LaTex?

Tags: symbols

Is there an elegant way of writing "iidN()" in LaTex, other than just writing it "iidN()"?

That is, is there a macro for "iid" and/or for normal distribution "N" symbols?

Comment: Scrap that. I meant `i.i.d. $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd recommend defining macros to reduce the number of keystrokes for `i.i.d.` and `\mathcal N`, if you use them a lot: this will.allow you to quickly type them out, and quickly change the way they're typeset if you decide to. For instance:

```
\newcommand\iid{i.i.d.}
\newcommand\pN{\mathcal{N}}

\iid~$X \sim \pN(\mu, \sigma^2)$
```

If you want to write `i.i.d.` without a nonbreaking space, I'd recommend `\iid\` (note the space).